Can we use any other alternative instead of using ADO.NET to access stored procedures?
Currently I'm using ASP.NET MVC for an ongoing application, to use the stored procedures I'm using ADO.NET. Is there any other way to call stored procedures from the code rather than using ADO.NET ?
public class EmployeeBusiness_Layer
{
    string connectionString =
               ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees
    {
        get
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllEmployees", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                    employee.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                    employee.Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                    employee.City = rdr["City"].ToString();
                    employee.DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["DateOfBirth"]);

                    employees.Add(employee);
                }
            }

            return employees;
        }
    }
}

I need an other alternative instead of using ADO.NET

you can surely write your own DB-adapter, but why? What's your problem with the above? We may help you way better, if we knew why you want this.

FYI EF Core can map stored procedure result sets to entities.

Hi Mark there's nothing wrong with the above code but it's quiet hard to understand every time while setting up the DB context configuration it's confusing since I'm beginner and still in learning steps, I need a roadmap on how to approach/handle  this kind of operations.
Thank you

@Abishek what's the actual problem? Why are you searching for an alternative? There's nothing wrong with ADO.NET and ALL other libraries eventually use ADO.NET. Database providers are only built for ADO.NET (except some SQLite libraries). EF, NHibernate, Dapper, all use ADO.NET. setting up the DB context that's Entity Framework, not ADO.NET. Are you confusing the two perhaps? One is the data access library, the other is a high level ORM

I'm assuming that you don't really care whether ADO.NET is used - you simply don't want to deal with the messy API - is that correct? If so, Dapper, EF, or anything similar are your friend. Wanting to bypass ADO.NET entirely would be a very extreme operation.

Hey Marc Thanks for the heads up but, working on EF Core is confusing, i just finished learning C# and SQL server, Right now I'm working on a web application which performs basic crud operations by watching a crash course on ASP.NET MVC But as i mentioned earlier it's hard to understand these concepts I need a roadmap for how to work on these things. Thank you

I give you Dapper (which is a utility library that deals with all the ADO.NET stuff for you):
using var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
return con.Query<Employee>("spGetAllEmployees").AsList();

The lack of even things like Open() is not a typo.
If you need parameters, the second parameter makes that simple:
string region = ...
DateTime fromDate = ...
return con.Query<Employee>("spGetAllEmployees",
    new { region, fromDate }).AsList();

